# Issues with adding a pod file to my Xcode project

Tags: cocoapods

I've been trying to create a pod file for my project in my directory using the terminal, but I'm running into the issue shown below, any suggestions?

I tried restarting my Mac and even tried to add one to a different project but to no avail. Also couldn't seem to find any other instances of this occurring.

Here's the terminal output:

```
Matts-Mac-mini:~ sarabytestudios$ cd /Users/sarabytestudios/Desktop/Blurr\Messenger/Blurr\ Messenger.xcodeproj 
Matts-Mac-mini:Blurr Messenger.xcodeproj sarabytestudios$ pod init
[!] No xcode project found, please specify one
Matts-Mac-mini:Blurr Messenger.xcodeproj sarabytestudios$
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to create your `PodFile` in the same directory as your `Blurr Messenger.xcodeproj`.

In your case should be in `/Users/sarabytestudios/Desktop/Blurr\Messenger/`.

In that directory, create a file called `PodFile` where you must declare the cocoapods you want to include in your project (you can do it by hand or call `pod init`). The you must type `pod install`.

After that, you must open the new generated file called `Blurr Messenger.xcworkspace`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Run '*pod init*' command inside the project directory(directory containing YourProject.xcodeproj file)(This will create a Podfile, a YourProject.xcworkspace file, Podfile.lock file and a Pods folder)

2) Run '*pod install*' command inside the same directory.

3)Open your project using YourProject.xcworkspace file and NOT the YourProject.xcodeproj file(otherwise build fails).