# Multiple xcode projects found, please specify one

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

When I try to run the pod init command at mac terminal. It says

> [!] Multiple Xcode projects found, please specify one

Comment: Can check in your path how many Xcode targets are there

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/738

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes, even when you are in the project folder that contains only one Xcode project, it will still raise that same error. However strange, it can be quickly remedied by denoting the intended Xcode project as so:

```
pod init <fullname of Xcode project here>
```

e.g.:

```
pod init myApp.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your pod file in the same directory in which your project
please follow below steps like

```
/Users/directory/Desktop/projectFolder/.
```

In project directory, you have to create your pod file by **pod** **init** command
 then use **pod** **install** to install pods

then open project.xcworkspace.

Please refer this link also, if my answer not helpful to you
[Issues with adding a pod file to my Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28003229/8061359)